# Ordinal form of an unknown value

Tags: word-choice

In some science and engineering literature, it is common to right the ordinal form of an unknown number *m* as *mth*. While the ordinal form of number 1 is first, it is also commonly written as 1st. I was wondering what would be the most appropriate way to write the ordinal form of *(m-1)*? *(m-1)th* or *(m-1)st*?

Comment: Could "second-to-last" work? Even if you don't know the exact number of items, it unambiguously means "the one before the last", so if "last" were the Nth item, "second-to-last" would be the (N-1)th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(m-1)th is still appropriate.  The expression in parentheses will still be read without the ordinal, so consider how it sounds when spoken—em-minus-oneth makes more sense than em-minus-onest.

I should also note that it's common to avoid the problem entirely through rephrasing (e.g. 'the value at index (m-1)'), but that may not be applicable to your field.

Comment: I was reading it as em-minus-first.

Comment: @Blade While it may vary from person to person (software dev myself), em-minus-first sounds to me like the mth value minus the first value, rather than the value at m-1.

Comment: Yeah, I would probably say em-minus-first, with the stress somehow avoiding any possible confusion, in which case I would write (m-1)st, if I had to - although I don't think I've ever actually written that, because as @AmaiKotori says, it's often easier to rephrase. But I would have no problem with someone saying em-minus-oneth and writing (m-1)th - I think it's just personal preference :)